# String after a Variable .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

I'm stucked in a little problem:

I want to make a short link to let the user view the images of the user "test.test".

My code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$/images images.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

Example:

website.com/tester.tester/images            <== This has to be the end-result

Full Code here:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine


RewriteRule ^(login|settings|friends|gallery|logout|signup|administrator)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ profile.php?user-id=home [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteCond $1 !^index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]

# RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L] #Umlaute müssen gehen!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You closed the expression prematurely with `$`, which would cause an error.

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)/images$ images.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

Your file should now look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(login|settings|friends|gallery|logout|signup|administrator)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ profile.php?user-id=home [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)\/images$ images.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]

# RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L] #Umlaute müssen gehen!!
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to not work... I updated the question maybe this could help to understand.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't have anything regarding the above rule (or your original)...

Comment: But I thinks its important where to place the code. And I tried toput  it above the RewriteCondition and it seems not wo work, after the RewriteCondition it does not make sense ( no logik behind of it ). I will look how to use your code and place an anwer here. Thanks for help! :D

Comment: The "**/**" before `images$` must be "**\/**" (backslash + slash). But, well I tried it also and it works a bit better now. Thanks for updating and answering, again! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried my best and hope it will work. But I'm not happy about that:

The Updated Code:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule ^(login|settings|friends|gallery|logout|signup|administrator)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ profile.php?user-id=home [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\/images [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)\/images$ images.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\/images\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)\/images\/$ images.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\/images\/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^index [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)\/$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

The Result is correct, but if the user types in "tester.tester/" wrong page is loaded.

This is annoying me. BUT I tried it and even this little thing might be solved by PHP (I don't really know)

Thanks for all Answers!! :D